# regular expression negative lookahed

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I'm trying to extract the names of firms from the text.

I found out that firm's names starts with Capital letters and some of them contains ' and ' or ' de ' or ' & ' or 'of' inside it.

So I wrote the regular expression that catches them

:  `(?:[A-Z]+[\w'-]*\s?(?:&\s|and\s|de\s|of\s)?)+%?`

For example, from the sentence

> "The companys largest customer, Wal-Mart Stores, Inc. and its
>   affiliated companies, accounted for approximately 25% of net sales
>   during fiscal year 2009 and 24% during fiscal years 2008 and 2007."

This regex matches out

> "The", "Wal-Mart Stores", "Inc"

However, I am stuck with two problems.

Problem 1:

I found out that company's segment, product, division, category, sales names are also matched since It also begins with capitals. However, I don't want to extract those names along with companies names.

Problem 2 :

I don't want to get names which starts with S(s)ale(s) of/by/in or sold

For example,

> ;;;;;In fiscal 2005, the Company derived
>   approximately 21% ($4,782,852) of its consolidated revenues from
>   continuing operations from direct transactions with Kmart Corporation.
>   Sales of Computer products are important for us. However, Computer's Parts and
>   Display Segment sale has been decreasing.

According to my regex wrote above, it extracts
['In', "Company', 'Kmart Corporation', ***'Sales of Computer', "Computer's Parts and Display Segment"***]

Since, I don't want to get 'Sales of Computer' and 'Computer's Parts and Display Segment'

I tried to use negative look ahead / look behind

Bellows are what I've been trying so far:

1. I added negative look ahead (***(?![Ss]egments?|[Pp]roducts?|programs?|[Dd]ivisions?|[Cc]ategor(?:y|ies)|[Ss]ales?)***)

   (?:[A-Z]+[\w'-]*\s?(?:&\s|and\s|de\s|of\s)?)+*(?![Ss]egments?|[Pp]roducts?|programs?|[Dd]ivisions?|[Cc]ategor(?:y|ies)|[Ss]ales?)*

However, It ***still matches "Computer's Parts and Display Segment"...!***

2. negative look behind is even worse...

I added **(?** at the beginning of my regex.

However, It seems like negative look behind expression cannot contain grouping or | ...

Whit such a huge frustration, I wrote few more regex for each cases and used set operations to deal with this problem.

However, I wonder is there any single regex that can do exactly what I expect in a one - shot??

Thanks for reading!

Comment: There is over 5 million companies in the US. World wide,. ? You're not going to match companies in sentences no matter what you do or try.

Comment: @sln I'm dealing with the matching problem in another way. I just want to extract words starting with capital letter but not belonging some specific cases I stated above

Comment: You should definitely give NLP a try. http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: I believe you should even give ML a try. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html